# Php photo editing leads to black line on photo

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick, gd

Hi what i'm doing is grabbing the size of the original image then creating a new image ($image_p) with those dimensions then rotating it. Sometimes though when i rotate an image on the server the image comes out with a black line on the border.  btw I'm rotating jpegs

How can i remove that black line? Thanks

php file

```
 $angle = (Input::get('angle') * -1);   

 $width = getimagesize($new_temp_image_filepath)[0];
    $height = getimagesize($new_temp_image_filepath)[1];

    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

//grab temporary file   
    $src_imgbinary = File::get($new_temp_image_filepath);
    //turn temp file string into image resource
    $src_image = imagecreatefromstring($src_imgbinary);

 imagecopyresampled($image_p, $src_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);

    $rotated_image = imagerotate($image_p, $angle, 0);
    //create image file based on extension and replace existing file in temp folder
    $image_ext = exif_imagetype($new_temp_image_filepath);

    if ($image_ext == IMAGETYPE_GIF) {

        imagegif($rotated_image, $new_temp_image_filepath);
    } elseif ($image_ext == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {

        imagepng($rotated_image, $new_temp_image_filepath, 0);
    } else {

        imagejpeg($rotated_image, $new_temp_image_filepath, 100);
    }
```

Comment: what angle do you use? it can be problem with rounding, also check last argument of imagerotate - it used for color

Comment: I use increments of 90 degrees. If i do counterclosewise I use -90

Comment: avoid using rotation for 90 degrees, as they have to use floating calculations, for 90 degrees its better to use your own rotate, also check imagesetinterpolation, play with different modes, maybe it will help, first try IMG_BICUBIC_FIXED and IMG_NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR